# Can you play Destiny on the 360 and the One on the same account at the same time?

Tags: xbox-network, destiny

Can you play Destiny on both consoles at the same time on the same account? I have a copy of the game for both, and I was thinking that if my brother also played on my account, but on the 360, maybe we could rank up faster.

Answer (score 6):

No.

If you try to connect to Destiny on more than one device on an account, you will get the following error message:

> Error
>
> Could not connect to Destiny servers. Please check your network configuration and try again.
>
> For more information on resolving this issue visit help.bungie.net and search for error code: weasel

You will get this error message on whichever machine was logged on first, at the point that the second person selects a character. This happens even if you pick a different character.

Comment: Sitting through twenty minutes of the game updating was so not worth it to find this out, btw. Haha.

Comment: We salute you for your time sacrifice!